# Attribute referencing two foreign keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I created a table like this in SQL

```
create table  WEATHER_STATION.Humidade 
(
    valor_observado int ,
    data_observacao date ,
    unidade_medida varchar(15),
    id_observacao int identity(1,1) primary key,
    estacao varchar(30) 
    foreign key (estacao) references WEATHER_STATION.Pessoa_singular(estacao_nome),
    foreign key (estacao) references WEATHER_STATION.Estaçao_meteorologica(localidade)
)
```

Then, I insert values with this code:

```
INSERT INTO WEATHER_STATION.Humidade 
VALUES (83,'2020-01-24','%','Albergaria(amadora)')

INSERT INTO WEATHER_STATION.Humidade 
VALUES (83,'2020-01-23','%','Aveiro')
```

With both I got this error :

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Humidade__estaca__00CA12DE". The conflict occurred in database "p4g8", table "WEATHER_STATION.Estaçao_meteorologica", column 'localidade'.
>
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Humidade__estaca__7FD5EEA5". The conflict occurred in database "p4g8", table "WEATHER_STATION.Pessoa_singular", column 'estacao_nome'.

My question is: is it possible that one attribute references two foreign keys from different tables?

Comment: Possible, yes. But does it make any sense? In most cases the FK references a primary key in the other table, which typically is an integer. varchar(30) primary keys and foreign keys are a bit unusual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly can.

But the way you phrase it is misleading. A column does not "point" to another table. A foreign key "relates" column(s) from one table to a key on another table. When a column is *related* to more than one key on a foreign table, I call them "forking foreign keys", but that's just me.

Consider the following example:

```
create table a (
  b int primary key not null,
  c int unique not null
);

create table d (
  e int,
  f int,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (e) references a (b),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (e) references a (c),
  constraint fk3 foreign key (f) references a (b),
  constraint fk4 foreign key (f) references a (c)
);
```

In this case you have four foreign keys with two columns. Using your "point" lingo you can say that:

- e -> b
- e -> c
- f -> b
- f -> c

So `e` points twice and `f` points twice as well. Also `b` and `c` are pointed twice each one.

Finally, one interesting side effect is that, since `e` points twice to the table `a` that **single value** may be actually pointing to **two different rows** at once. This could be very tricky for INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs. The errors you are seeing are probably related to this side effect. You'll need to be careful when modifying the data to keep FKs valid.